# Finding number of ways to make a sum in coin changing?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a value N, if we want to make change for N cents, and we have infinite supply of each of S = { S1, S2, .. , Sm} valued coins, how many ways can we make the change? The order of coins doesn’t matter.

For example, for N = 4 and S = {1,2,3}, there are four solutions: {1,1,1,1},{1,1,2},{2,2},{1,3}. So output should be 4. For N = 10 and S = {2, 5, 3, 6}, there are five solutions: {2,2,2,2,2}, {2,2,3,3}, {2,2,6}, {2,3,5} and {5,5}. So the output should be 5.

Now, I have a doubt. Why can't we do something like,

`arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2] + arr[i-3]`

This is basically, `arr[i]` stores the number of ways to make the sum `i`. The approach I am giving here is somewhat similar to the `n stairs problem` which is that I can climb a fix number of stairs, that is, let's say 1 stair at a time or 2 stairs at a time and I have to calculate the total number of ways of reaching the top from bottom. Why can't we use a similar approach in this question?

Comment: Why don't you try to implement that idea, and put it here? I don't think we have any rule not to use any type of approach/idea.

Comment: What I meant to ask was, will that be the correct approach of solving this problem? Moreover, I am not asking you to help to me code the problem or debug some code, all I want to know is, will this be the correct approach of solving the above mentioned problem?

Comment: It wouldn't work because you might add identical cases (assuming the order is ignored).

Comment: Dynamic programming is usually mentioned as an alternative to recursion.  That being said, can you think about how a recursive solution might differ from what you have in mind?

Comment: The point is, it is better to see your implementation and tell which gone wrong. With your description only, it is hard to say anything (Pseudocode, at least). Agree?

Comment: I guess what would work though would be to store the solutions in each case, and then "add" them (discarding the identical ones).

Comment: Then, why does it exactly work in the stairs problem where we have a similar problem?

Comment: @Pham Trung: The question is clear as it is, without more code.

Comment: @DouglasZare IMO, When you describe an algorithm, I think it is fair to expect pseudocode/code + explanation. It will help not just OP but also for the community.

Comment: @Pham Trung: What more do you want beyond arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2] + arr[i-3]? This explains what the attempt is, and it shows what is wrong. Surrounding it with unimportant code would not help anyone. It would make it worse.

Comment: @Pham Trung: Don't be melodramatic. That one line is already pseudocode for the very simple and straightforward algorithm he asked about. There is plenty of explanation. I can't reconcile your statements with actually reading the question. Did you overlook the one line formatted as code? I often see people request more and more code when there isn't a lack at all.

Comment: @DouglasZare I just think OP can verify his idea simple by implementing and try it, but he didn't , he just went straight here and ask a question, and it is not good for him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't we use a similar approach in this question?

It won't work because in the n stairs problem, the order is important. For e.g. if you are climbing 5 stairs, {1, 2, 1, 1} is counted as different to {1, 1, 2, 1}.

However in the making change problem only the total counts of each coin count, not the order you add them, so if you are making $5, {$1, $2, $1, $1} is the same as {$1, $1, $2, $1}. Therefore the simple memoization approach doesn't work, you would need to store all the possible ways of reaching arr[i], not just the total number.

For example, suppose you are trying to make $6 with $1 and $2. You can't just add the number of ways of making $4 to the number of ways of making $5, because (for example) one of the ways of making $4 is {$1, $1, $2} (which you can add $2 to to make $6 i.e. {$1, $1, $2, $2}), and one of the ways of making $5 is {$1, $2, $2} (to which you can add $1 to make $6 {$1, $2, $2, $1}).

However {$1, $2, $2, $1} and {$1, $1, $2, $2} shouldn't be counted separately.

Comment: Right. And how should I do that? Should I simply keep on storing all possible solutions at each step?

Comment: Well just storing a tuple with as many values as you have coins for each solution. It's not so complicated.

Comment: Got it. Amazing example. Cleared everything. @samgak, thanks a lot for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Samgak's answer explained how making change differs from climbing stairs 1 or 2 steps at a time: The order doesn't matter for making change, but order matters when you are climbing stairs.

You can do the problem using dynamic programming, but you need a more complicated state. Let `a[i][j]` be the number of ways to make change for i units of money, using only the first j denominations of coins. So, `a[0][0]=1`, `a[i][0] = 0` for i greater than 0, and for j greater than 0, `a[i][j] = a[i][j-1] + a[i-Sj][j-1] + a[i-2*Sj][j-1]+...`